# Trying to loop through points and create splines in Animation Nodes

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm trying to use Animation Nodes to loop through random points on a sphere and draw splines coming out from them, for some reason it only renders one spline, what am I missing here?

[image: screenshot]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a new Generator Output Spline List to the loop and use it to drive a Curve Object Output:

[image]